# How to get second and third rows using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to get the first row of the location record in order to added time,

My query as follows,

```
private Location GetFirstRecord()
{
    return clientContext.Lobbies.Where(location => location.FkBranchId == locationRecord.FkBranchId && !location.FkAppointmentId.HasValue && location.Status == 1 && location.IsActive).OrderBy(location => location.AddedTime).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The above query works fine, now I need to get second, third, fourth.....10th row records from the location. Do I need to write separate 10 separate queries to get data? or have any other possible way to do it. I don't have an idea to how to get second, third, fourth... values from the records. please provide me a sample query to do this. thanks in advance

Comment: `Take(10).ToList()` to get the first 10 records.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Skip` method to get specific record like this

```cs
private Location GetRecord(int skip)
{
    return clientContext.Lobbies.Where(location => location.FkBranchId == locationRecord.FkBranchId && !location.FkAppointmentId.HasValue && location.Status == 1 && location.IsActive)
        .OrderBy(location => location.AddedTime)
        .Skip(skip)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

and use

```cs
var data = GetRecord(0);//First Record
var data = GetRecord(1);//Second record
var data = GetRecord(9);// 10th record
```

Answer (score 1):

Do I need to write 10 separate queries to get data?

> No, you can use [`Skip(n)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netcore-3.1) to skip first n records and then get First record by FirstOrDefault()

Like,

```
private Location GetLocation(int skipIndex)
{
    return clientContext.Lobbies
             .Where(location => location.FkBranchId == locationRecord.FkBranchId
                                && !location.FkAppointmentId.HasValue 
                                 && location.Status == 1 && location.IsActive)     //Filter using where clause
             .OrderBy(location => location.AddedTime)  //Order by AddedTime
             .Skip(skipIndex)   //Skip first n records
             .FirstOrDefault();   //Take the record at given position.
}
```

You need to pass `skipIndex = 2` as a parameter to get third Location.

```
var secondLocation = GetLocation(1); 
var thirdLocation = GetLocation(2); 
...
```

Comment: No, I don't need to get all the 10 records, I just need to get only one record based on its position what I need. If I pass 2, I need a seconds record, If I pass 3 I need a 3rd record. likewise